# Junit 5 tag not working with Gradle 6.5.1

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, junit5

I am learning JUnit 5 with Gradle 6.5.1. I have 2 questions.

```
public class FruitCalculator {
    public int addFruit(int fruit1, int fruit2) {
        return fruit1 + fruit2;
    }

    public int subFruit(int fruit1, int fruit2) {
        return fruit1 - fruit2;
    }
}
```

Test case class

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
public class FruitCalculatorTest {
    @Test
    @Tag("add")
    void addFruitTestTag1() {
        System.out.println("FruitCalculatorTest.addFruitTestTag1");
        FruitCalculator fruitCalculator = new FruitCalculator();
        assertEquals(2, fruitCalculator.addFruit(1, 1), "1 fruit + 1 fruit is 2 fruit");
    }

    @Test
    @Tag("sub")
    void subFruitTestTag1() {
        System.out.println("FruitCalculatorTest.subFruitTestTag1");
        FruitCalculator fruitCalculator = new FruitCalculator();
        assertEquals(1, fruitCalculator.subFruit(2, 1), "2 fruit - 1 fruit is 1 fruit");
    }
}
```

Gradle file is

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2')
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.2')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'add'
        excludeTags 'sub'
    }
}
```

1-> @ tag is not working. if I run using IntelliJ, it's running all 4 test cases.

2 -> in cmd -> `gradle clean build test` printing no output whether the test is passed or failed.

```
~junit5$ gradle clean build test

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
```

even the System.out is also not printing.

Answer (score 0):

to get the junit System.out and err

see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

add to test { } block

```
// show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
```

Comment: I tried with the test block as well, but no change in output.